# How do I copy a range including hidden cells(by filter)?

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I know basically the same questions has previosly been asked and answered on many forums, including stack overflow, but none of the answers satisfy my requirements.

I want to press a button, which will copy a range of around 100 cells. I then want to press a different button, in a totally different workbook (which is in no way connected to the first workbook) and that will paste my copied range.

The issue is that I have a filter in my workbook, which will hide some of the cells in the range. These are not being copied but I need to copy the full range. (The reason I want to copy the full range is because the values need to align when I paste it)

My issue with all other given solutions are:

1. One solution is to remove the filter when I copy the range. This is not something I want to do as I don't know a way to restore the filter. If this is done before I paste the values, the copied range will "exit?" (it will no longer be copied). And due to the files not being connected, I can't perform any actions with the paste button.
2. Using a loop to copy the range as a array(Variant), This doesn't work since I can't "transfer" that variant to another workbook which is not connected. Or at least I don't know how to do that.

Is there any other method I can use?

Comment: Could you have both workbooks open a file at a known location?  If so, one could write the workbook name, sheet name, and address of the selected range and the other could read it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit of a hack, but because both workbooks have access to the set of custom lists defined for Excel, you could create a custom list with the information needed to identify the source range from the target workbook.  The code for the copy button would record the range address, sheet name, and workbook name of the selected range as follows:

```
Sub copy_range_info()
    Application.AddCustomList Array("DeleteMe", Selection.Address, Selection.Parent.Name, Selection.Parent.Parent.Name)
End Sub
```

On the destination worksheet, the code to paste data would look like this:

```
Sub paste_range_from_other_workbook()
  Dim last_list As Variant
  last_list = Application.GetCustomListContents(Application.CustomListCount)
  If last_list(1) = "DeleteMe" Then
     Workbooks(last_list(4)).Worksheets(last_list(3)).Range(last_list(2)).Copy
     ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     Application.DeleteCustomList Application.CustomListCount
  Else
    MsgBox "You need to copy a range first using that special button"
  End If
End Sub
```

Because this creates a custom list in Excel that will be permanent, I'm deleting it just before the "else" in the code above.  It might be advisable to scan the custom list and delete any lists that begin with "DeleteMe" so if someone does a copy without a corresponding paste, it won't result in more than one custom list of this type.

Comment: Thank you! 
This is not something I'm familiar with. It will probably work, but i'm sceptical to the "permanent" part and i'm not sure about the "duplicateability" of this. I will need 40 unique "paste" buttons and 40 unique "copy" button,. 
Paste button in 1 workbook and the copy buttons are from 40 different workbooks. 

I think I rather live with the filter always messing up when I copy then above solution, this is only because this is new and i'm not familiar with it.
But thank you very much for the effort.

Comment: I'm not sure of your environment, but if you are talking about needing to put buttons in 40 different workbooks, it might be better to make a custom tab in the Excel Ribbon to do this.  It could be installed on just your machine using your "personal macro workbook" it could be set up as an "add-in" an installed on any number of machines.  Then the copy button and the paste button would work on which ever worksheet is active when they are clicked.  If you share a bit more about what you are doing, I may be able to recommend a better solution.

Comment: This would aslo probably work, but it's more complicated. And the current solution works fine. 

the 40 "paste" buttons I have are all reffering to the same macro, but the code take advantage of "activesheet". There are 40 different sheets within the workbook and all sheets include 1 paste button. So it's not very complicated.